# Debug image processing into Qt loop

Tags: qt, opencv, qt4

I have the following algorithm (working):

1. Acquire image from webcam
2. Process image
3. Send image to GUI and show it

The GUI interface is programmed with Qt, and all image acquirement and processing is been doing with OpenCV. There are 3 classes involved, call them `Acquire`, `Process` and `Gui`.

`Acquire` (Inherits from QObject) grabs the image and calls to `Process` (Does not inherit from QObject) to make the image processing. `Process` returns the result to `Acquire`, who emits a signal caught by `Gui` (Inherits from QObject), who converts the image (in Mat format) to QImage and draws it.

I am introducing changes into the `Process` class and I would like to have a visual feedback. As everything is been executed into the Qt's loop I can not use the `cv::namedWindow` and `cv::imshow` functions (nothing appears).

The question is: There is any quick method to make visual debugging to know what is happening inside `Process` without make `Process` and `Gui` friends, or connecting them using the signal/slot mechanism or any other solution that involves big changes into the program structure?

Comment: Your problem is not clear. You've said that you can send data from Process to Gui. Why can't you use this ability to send debugging data you need to display?

Comment: I did not. Acquire grabs the image, sends it to Process, Process returns the result to Acquire and Acquire emits a Signal caught by Gui, who paint the processed image on the screen. Anyway, I will edit the question to make it more clear

Comment: You can create another QWidget in Process, display it in separate window and put debug information in it. Also you can write debug information to files.

Comment: Process inherits from QObject to emit signals (it does not draw anything in the screen). To create all needed code to draw a widget for debug information requires to many code changes (I want to keep the debug as simple as possible). Save images to files is possible... but I am debugging video

Comment: You can create another class and put all code for debug output into it. Connect Process to this class to send debug information.

Comment: Based to your comment I've created a class that inherits from QDialog and shows the cv::Mat images as QImage. It works and do not require to much aditional code (even I'm thinking to create a specialized class for future projects), so, If you put your comment as answer I will be glad to accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create another class and put all code for debug output into it. Connect Process to this class to send debug information.

Comment: I have created a small project showing how to do it. Maybe someone can find it useful: https://github.com/mmartinortiz/DebugingCvWithQt